# How to extract all rows, for which row a particular criteria is met? Details in description

Tags: etl, lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to load a set of policy numbers in my Target based on below criteria using Informatica PowerCenter.

I want to select all those rows of policy numbers, for which policy the Rider = 0

This is my source: -

```
Policy  Rider   Plan
1234    0   1000
1234    1   1010
1234    2   3000
9090    0   2000
9090    2   2545
4321    3   2000
4321    1   2000
```

Target should look like this: -

```
Policy  Rider   Plan
1234    0   1000
1234    1   1010
1234    2   3000
9090    0   2000
9090    2   2545
```

The policy number 4321 would not be loaded.

If I use filter as Rider = 0, then I miss out on below rows: -

```
1234    1   1010
1234    2   3000
9090    0   2000
9090    2   2545
```

What would be ideal way to load this kind of data using PowerCenter Designer?

Answer (score 1):

Take the same source in one more qualifier in same mapping, use a filter as Rider=0 to get list of unique policy numbers that has Rider=0, then use a joiner with your regular source on policy number. This should work.

Another method, sort your data based on policy and Rider, and use variable ports with condition similar to below.

```
v_validflag=IIF(v_policy_prev!=policy, IIF(Rider=0, 'valid','invalid'), v_validflag)
v_policy_prev=policy
```

Then filter valid records.

Comment: If I use the first option, how would I take forward the remaining attributes of the second column? Below is the output I am getting.

```
1234    0   1000
1234    0   1000
1234    0   1000
9090    0   2000
9090    0   2000
```

I am getting the right number of rows in Target but they are all identical.

Comment: Prepare a solution, run, verify. Investigate, debug. In case of a problem, post some details with screenshot of your implementation - we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Yes, use a distinct of them. And then pull all your source in another source qualifier. Join both of them using a joiner based on policy.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. Here are two...
**First**:
It'll look like:

```
                                      // AGGREGATOR \\ 
SOURCE >> SOURCE QUALIFIER >> SORTER <<              >> JOINER >> TARGET
                                      \\============//
```

Connect all ports from Source Qualifier (SQ) to SORTER transformation (or sort in SQ itself) and define sorting Key for ‘Policy’ and ‘Rider’. After that split stream into two pipelines:

1. - Connect ‘Policy’ and ‘Rider’ to FILTER transformation and filter records by ‘Rider’ = 0.
    - After that link ‘Policy’ (only) to AGGREGATOR and set Group By to ‘YES’ for ‘Policy’. 
   - Add a new port with FIRST or MAX function for ‘Policy’ port. This is to remove duplicate ‘Policy’-es.
   - Indicate ‘Sorted Input’ in the AGGREGATOR properties.
   - After that link ‘Policy’ from AGR to JOINER as **Master** in Port tab.

   2.
   - Second stream, from SORTER, directly link to above JOINER (with aggregated ‘Policy’) as Detail. 
   - Indicate ‘Sorted Input’ in the JOINER properties. 
   - Set Join Type as ‘Normal Join’ and Join Condition as POLICY(master)=POLICY(detail) in JOINER properties.

... Target

Second option:
Just Override SQL in Source Qualifier...

```
WITH PLC as (        
select POLICY
from SRC_TBL
where RIDER=0)
select s.POLICY, s.RIDER, s.PLAN
from PLC p left JOIN SRC_TBL s on s.POLICY = p.POLICY;
```

*may vary depend on your source table constructions...*